# Python lazy dictionary evaluation

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement, lazy-evaluation

Python evangelists will say the reason Python doesn't have a switch statement is because it has dictionaries.  So... how can I use a dictionary to solve this problem here?
The problem is that all values are being evaluated some and raising exceptions depending on the input.

This is just a dumb example of a class that stores a number or a list of numbers and provides multiplication.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return {
            (False, False): self._value * other._value                        ,
            (False, True ): [self._value * o for o in other._value]           ,
            (True , False): [v * other._value for v in self._value]           ,
            (True , True ): [v * o for v, o in zip(self._value, other._value)],
        }[(isinstance(self._value, (tuple, list)), isinstance(other._value, (tuple, list)))]

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self._value)
    __repr__ = __str__



>>> x = MyClass(2.0)
>>> y = MyClass([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
>>> print x
2.0
>>> print y
[3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>> print x * y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __mul__
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

One way that I could solve it would be to prefix each value with "lambda : " and at after the dictionary lookup call the lambda function .... "}(isinsta ...)"

Is there a better way?

Comment: Methods that take *any kind of value* are about the worst thing you can do from a OOP point of view and that's why the code looks so ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, define small lambdas for these different options:

```
    def __mul__(self, other): 
        scalar_times_scalar = lambda x,y: x*y
        scalar_times_seq    = lambda x,y: [x*y_i for y_i in y]
        seq_times_scalar    = lambda x,y: scalar_times_seq(y,x)
        seq_times_seq       = lambda x,y: [x_i*y_i for x_i,y_i in zip(x,y)]
        self_is_seq, other_is_seq = (isinstance(ob._value,(tuple, list)) 
                                                    for ob in (self, other))
        fn = {
            (False, False): scalar_times_scalar, 
            (False, True ): scalar_times_seq, 
            (True , False): seq_times_scalar, 
            (True , True ): seq_times_seq, 
            }[(self_is_seq, other_is_seq)] 
        return fn(self._value, other._value)
```

Ideally, of course, you would define these lambdas only once at class or module scope.  I've just shown them in the `__mul__` method here for ease of reference.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches here:

- Some `if` statements. For just four combinations of `True` and `False`, it's not that bad. Sequences of `if` ... `elif` ... `elif` ... clauses are, from what I've seen, not uncommon in Python code.
- Creating the dict once (as a class field, rather than an instance field), and storing (lambda) functions inside it. This scales better than the previous approach and is faster for many options (although I don't know the value of "many").

Answer (score 1):

I think the main point here is readability.
A dictionary lookup as the one you showed is definitely difficult to read, and therefore to maintain.

In my opinion, main goal while writing software should be readability; for this reason, I would go for a set of if/elif explicitely comparing the two values (instead of having the mapping for the types); then if measurements shows performance concerns, other solutions (like a dictionary lookup with functions) could be explored.